# Insert multiple rows in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm very new to Laravel. Just getting around the MVC idea.

How would I go about writing in Laravel so I can insert / update multiple rows into my database? For one entry, correct me if I'm wrong, I can write my form in a View, which the content are shown based on my Controller 'create function' (e.g. where to gather data to input into my Select form input), it then checks my data in the Model and returns it to my Controller 'store' and saves it.

How does the data get passed to the database in the store function? How would I go about writing a form (same content - e.g. project_detail, project_name, project_price ) three or fours times, on one page. How do I pass the arrays so each array gets entered as a new row?

Comment: So there are a number of way to do what you want to do. Can you provide your attempts in code that you have already tried? Also, If you include your goal (what you want to happen) as well as your question, sometimes it makes it easier to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to create a shopping cart type functionality.

You can just create a single form to add items. then create a table that would list the items you've added. you can use ajax to submit your form. then store the items in a session. or you can use shopping car package. then display the added items to your view.

hope this gives you a little idea how to go about with your project.

Comment: Yes your right after storing data into session you can proceed insert batch operation so it is easy to insert.right..?

Comment: Yup. you're correct. so when you're done selecting items. then you post or batch submit it. you loop through your items and save it one by one.