# Insert Tabular Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have multiple input in multiple rows like given below

```
<tr><td>Input 1</td><td>Input 1 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Input 2</td><td>Input 2 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Input 3</td><td>Input 3 1</td></tr>
```

Now, I have to insert these input data into mySQL database.

How to insert using php/laravel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert multiple rows in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720907/insert-multiple-rows-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

First create a table in MySQL such as like that

```
CREATE TABLE TableValues (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
input1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
imput2 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

then write the server and database connection information and use below code,

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO TableValues (imput1, input2)
VALUES ('Input1', 'Input 11')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```